# How to compare these parameters through a cost function?

Tags: design, active-filter, optimization

I am comparing three filter designs based on different criteria. Basically my question is about what is like the best way to compute like a number, or figure of merit to evaluate this criteria.

**CRITERIUM 1 (Worst component ratio -> ideally it is as close to 1 as possible)**

Filter A: 16

Filter B: 7

Filter C: 19

**CRITERIUM 2 (K passive sensitivity > ideally as small as possible)**

Filter A: 3.6

Filter B: 46.8

Filter C: 3

**CRITERIUM 3 (wp passive sensitivity > ideally as small as possible)**

Filter A: 2

Filter B: 2

Filter C: 2

**CRITERIUM 4 (Q passive sensitivity > ideally as small as possible)**

Filter A: 1.6

Filter B: 42.6

Filter C: 1

**CRITERIUM 5 (Active normalized sensitivity > ideally as small as possible)**

Filter A: 2

Filter B: 16

Filter C: 2.4

**CRITERIUM 6 (Number of components > ideally fewest as possible)**

Filter A: 4

Filter B: 6

Filter C: 5

I am giving a weight of 20% to the first 4 criteria, then 15% to the third criterium and 5% to the last criterium.

How would you measure in all this criteria?

I was thinking about taking the best value, giving that a contribution of 1 and then proportionally calculate the contribution of the other criteria. But that for instance would make Filter B explode on criteria 2 and 4 (for example, criterium 2 -> best value is 3 for filter C, so  contribution of 1; filter A would have a contribution of 3.6/2=1.2 and for filter C a contribution  of 15.6!

Then I thought of summing the values and take a percentage. For criterium 2, filter A = 3.6/(3.6+3+46.8)=0.07; filter B = 0.88; filter C = 0.06. Seems better but I am not sure...

How would you approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a normalised "ideality" value, between 0 and 1 (the result of some overall "fitness" function), then I suggest you normalise each of the individual criteria, to also produce a value between 0 and 1.

How you do this depends on the bounds of the value your are assessing. For example, one of your criteria is "number of components", which I shall call \$Q_6\$. Lets say this has a lower bound (minimum) of \$Q_{6MIN}\$ (which is perfect), but can rise to any quantity (getting  worse). Then your "figure of merit" might be a reciprocal:

$$ F_6(Q_6) = \frac{1}{1 + Q_6 - Q_{6MIN}} $$

This yields a maximum of 1 when component count \$Q_6=Q_{6MIN}\$, diminishing towards zero as component count increases.

If you have clear lower and upper bounds \$Q_{MIN}\$ and \$Q_{MAX}\$, where bigger is better, then the function might be a linear mapping to between 0 and 1, corresponding to that range:

$$ F(Q) = \frac{Q-Q_{MIN}}{Q_{MAX}-Q_{MIN}} $$

If smaller is better, then:

$$ F(Q) = 1- \frac{Q-Q_{MIN}}{Q_{MAX}-Q_{MIN}} $$

When there is a known "optimal" value, say \$Q_{OPT}=5\$, and "merit" falls off with distance from this optimum, then you could take another reciprocal, this time related to the magnitude of that distance:

$$ F(Q) = \frac{1}{1+\left|Q-Q_{OPT}\right|} $$

Once you have a set of normalised fitness functions for each criterion, \$F_1(Q_1), F_2(Q_2) \cdots F_N(Q_N)\$, and a set of weights \$W_1, W_2 \cdots W_N\$ associated with each function, overall fitness will then be:

$$ F_{ALL} = \frac{\sum^N_{n=1}{W_nF_n(Q_n)}}{\sum^N_{n=1}{W_n}} $$

By dividing the weighted sum by the sum of weights, we obtain another value between 0 and 1, where 0 is meritless, and 1 is perfect.